# Jquery, Jcarousel, first pagination item set to :active unless another is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jcarousel

I have been able to get the clicked pagination item to respond to a css selector.  But I can't get it to be :active if the user uses the next and back buttons vs the pagination.

```
ul.jcarousel-control li a:focus {background-position:0 -11px}
ul.jcarousel-control li a:active {background-position:0 -11px}
```

That stuff makes it work if the item is clicked but you use the next button to scroll, it doesn't highlight then next one.

I also need it to highlight the first one when the page loads.

any help is greatly appreciated.

```
jQuery('.jcarousel-control a').bind('click', function() {
    carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(jQuery(this).text()));
    return false;
});

jQuery('#mycarousel-next').bind('click', function() {
    carousel.next();
    return false;
});

jQuery('#mycarousel-prev').bind('click', function() {
    carousel.prev();
    return false;
});
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://mheidzir.wordpress.com/2009/06/25/how-to-highlight-external-controller-for-jcarousel/) shows you how to do this.  You need to add two call back functions (itemVisibleInCallback and itemVisibleOutCallback) to add/remove a div class from the selected image.